# Should a Poisson regression be carried out with only 3 data points?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, count-data, small-sample

I'm trying to test the relationship between the number of adults counted and the percentage heather cover over 3 areas.

The data looks like this:

```
Area      Cover    Count
Field1     53.7      216
Field2     19.5        2
Field3     39.8     6106
```

Given that count data is involved I was going to carry out a Poisson regression.

I know a relationship is unlikely given this data but my question is, is 3 data points enough for a regression analysis? This is important as I also want to test the relationship between adult counts and nest number, adult counts and vegetation height etc. but all of which only have 3 data points as I was only studying 3 areas on a site.

With this type of data, I don't know if any other test could be used given that it is count data.

I'm still a beginner when it comes to stats so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using R to carry out all my analyses.

Comment: What does a plot of these data tell you?

Answer (score 3):

With this limited of a data set, you can actually just think about what the data are showing you on a case by case basis. In your case, there is not much to show. In Field 1, you have what seems like a 'large' number of adults (not sure what organism this is - if for example beetles, then perhaps 200 beetles is not a lot of beetles in a field?) and a pretty large amount of heather. Field 2, smaller amount of heather and smaller number of adults. All good. Field 3 breaks the nice little pattern. Without more data, there's no way to know if this is indicative of a 'non-relationship' or just variability.

If you have an opportunity to gather data to your heart's content, you should probably work on doing a power calculation. I suspect that you have to take data opportunitistically and that it's a lot of work to collect data for a single field.  Something else to keep in mind is that you have percentage as well as count data. Percentage data (capped at something like 100%) sometimes needs to be dealt with as well, either through something like logistic regression, an arc-sine transformation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was looking at butterflies and I was limited to three fields and the butterflies are now no longer around. Field 3 is actually the historic location for this butterfly and Field 1 and Field 2 are regenerated so I was trying to see whether they were using the regenerated areas yet. Obviously they are in Field 1 and not quite in Field 2 but it will be a while before they reach the population of the original Field 3.

Comment: In that case, a regression of adult count on heather is definitely not the right method. That regression would merely tell if you the relationship between heather and butterflies, which presumably you already know? It sounds like you need to keep collecting data over the years to eventually construct a time series to demonstrate if the butterflies are returning or not. In this case it would be preferable to collect information on area of heather rather than percentage, since that will help control for comparing fields that are probably of different overall size.

Comment: This is actually for a Masters dissertation which I will be handing in in less than a month. But I understand what you mean and will definitely recommend that this work be repeated. Maybe I'll get to do it, who knows!